# Python used to run Java JAR, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, python, jar, stanford-nlp, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Pythons' `subprocess` module to run a command.

The command is used to run **java JAR file**.

When I run it via **terminal**, it runs fine producing the desired output.

The **JAVA** command via terminal:

`java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref,depparse -file input/input.txt`

I've written a simple Python script to run the same command.

```
from subprocess import call
def main():
    call(['java', '-cp', '\"*\"','-Xmx2g','edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP','-annotators','tokenize,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref,depparse', '-file', 'input/input.txt'])
```

Terminal Command (from the same folder where I ran the JAVA Command):

```
python script.py
```

Output here is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class     edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
```

I'm missing as to what is not same when I run it from python or run it from the terminal?
What is present in the terminals environment that pythons `call()` misses out?

Any insight or direction would kick start my project!

Comment: How do I about this then? Should I put in an actual Character encoded value or ASCII value? @user2357112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When typing `"*"` in your terminal, it just tells Linux not to expand `*` to "all the contents of the current folder", and just does nothing particular on Windows (double quotes are useful to protect against spaces). In both cases, `*` is passed to the java command line.

But when passed to `subprocess` as a `list` (it's different when passing a string, and I don't recommend doing that), `\"*\"` (no need for backslashes BTW) is passed to java _literally as `"*"` so it's not the same as passing `*`

So you have to just change that argument to `*` like this:

```
call(['java', '-cp', '*','-Xmx2g', ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, `"*"` is passed directly as part of `argv` and is not evaluated as a glob. That's because `subprocess.call()` does not invoke a shell. Rather, it calls the `exec()` system call directly.

You could fix this by any of the following:

1. Specify the shell. It should be the first argument, before `"java"`.
2. Include the `shell=True` argument in `call()`.
3. Add your classpath entries explicitly in `argv`.

For general cases you could take your pick, but because this is Java, #3 is probably your best option. Java is kinda weird about how it handles classpath wildcards and it varies by operating system, and in my experience, you'll have fewer headaches if you avoid wildcards in the classpath. See [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath/18793968)